# What is the hotkey for getting back a just-minimized (CMD+M) window?

Tags: macos, mac

I am using Mac OSX Yosemite (10.10.4)

When I hit the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to minimize a window, it'd be inconvenient to get it back. Is there any hotkey to get it back immediately?

Comment: In windows, pressing the key again should bring it back, I believe the same works in Mac OS. As I'm not sure, this is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: unfortunately not working